# Am I just missing a parenthesis somewhere?

Tags: formula, if

```
IF( ISPICKVAL(FPLHW_Brands__c,"NEH"),

 IF( RecordType.Name <> "NEH Realtor Enrollment",
 IF( whw_Renewal__c = False, "a2b29000000yBA7AAM","a2b29000000yBhmAAE",
 IF( whw_Renewal__c = True, "a2b29000000teCZAAY","a2b29000000yBhcAAE",

 IF( RecordType.Name <> "NEH Realtor Enrollment", 
 IF( whw_Renewal__c = False, "a2b29000000yBeEAAU","a2b29000000yBhhAAE",
 IF( whw_Renewal__c = True, "a2b29000000yBeJAAU","a2b29000000yBhJAAU"
)))))))
```

EDIT
Trying to accomplish this:

- If brand is NEH, and Record type isn’t Realtor, and it’s not a renewal, use A
- If brand is NEH and record type isn’t Realtor, and it IS a renewal, use B
- If Brand is NEH and Record type IS Realtor and it’s not a renewal, use C
- If brand is NEH and Record type IS Realtor and it IS a renewal, use D
- If Brand is FPLHW and Record type isn’t realtor, and it’s not a renewal, use E
- If Brand is FPLHW and Record type isn’t realtor, and it IS a renewal, use F
- If Brand is FPLHW and record type IS realtor, and it’s not a renewal, use G
- If Brand is FPLHW and record type IS realtor, and it IS a renewal, use H

This is returning the Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3, received 4 . I'm just banging my head against a wall at this point. I checked out the other similar questions but they don't seem to apply? I don't know, I'm new here. Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`IF` statements take 3 parameters, but you're providing 4 in most cases. Example:

`IF( whw_Renewal__c = False, "a2b29000000yBA7AAM","a2b29000000yBhmAAE",`

That is three parameters right there, but you added a comma and more IF statements after... that makes it 4.

I can't tell what you're trying to achieve, or I'd help rewrite the formula.

**UPDATE**

More info:

```
 IF( whw_Renewal__c = False, "a2b29000000yBA7AAM","a2b29000000yBhmAAE",
 IF( whw_Renewal__c = True, "a2b29000000teCZAAY","a2b29000000yBhcAAE",
```

These two statements are unnecessary. I mean, one is the opposite of the other.... so you will get two answers at the same time (the true part of one and the false part of the other). To simplify your formula, I'd expect the "true" value from the first to equal the "false" value from the second (and vice-versa)... and they don't match.

**UPDATE**

PEr your updated logic, here is how this formula could work (REMOVE THE COMMENTS BEFORE COMPILING)

```
IF( ISPICKVAL(FPLHW_Brands__c,"NEH"),
 //Brand is NEH
 IF( RecordType.Name <> "NEH Realtor Enrollment",
   //RT is NOT Realtor
   IF ( whw_Renewal__c = False, "A","B"),
   //RT is Realtor
   IF ( whw_Renewal__c = False, "C","D"))
 ),
 //Brand is NOT NEH    
 IF( RecordType.Name <> "NEH Realtor Enrollment",
   //RT is NOT Realtor
   IF ( whw_Renewal__c = False, "E","F"),
   //RT is Realtor
   IF ( whw_Renewal__c = False, "H","G"))
 )
)
```

Comment: We have 8 different records that we are trying to call, so in the part you reference I'm trying to use the top line as the Then and the bottom as the Else for IF record type <> "Realtor". I think I see what you're saying about there being two answers at the same time. I'll have to play with this new information for a minute.

Comment: A technique that works for me is to write the logic in pure english, and then replace that English with formula language. As a bonus, you could post that verbiage here for people to help

Comment: Okay, I posted my goal in the original.

Comment: Thank you for your fast responses to this. I feel it's really close, but it's now saying Extra ','. EDIT: I think i've moved past that error. i'm getting a compile size error now, so i think this formula will work, i just have to fix a few things on some other fields. Thank you, Sebastian!

Comment: you're welcome! Feel free to upvote/mark as good if you think this answer may benefit others